# Itext pdf setKeepTogether without repeating header row

Tags: java, itext

[image: example how my result would come]

I try to use below code to make sure title and content on same page but it header will be print out on every page.

```
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    table.setKeepTogether(true);
```

Then, i try to change setHeaderRow to 0 but the result will come like the picture:

```
    table.setHeaderRows(0);
    table.setKeepTogether(true);
```

How to make Title and Content on the same page but the title only on first page?

Comment: Have you tried `table.setSplitLate(false);` or isn't that what you're asking. Your question isn't entirely clear

Comment: thank you @BrunoLowagie, its works

Comment: In that case, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add rows that don't fit the current page, the default behavior is to split the table and to forward the row to the next page. This is what happens in your case: the first row fits the page, the second row doesn't. As a result, you have one row on one page, the other row on the next page.

You can change this default behavior by adding this line:

```
table.setSplitLate(false);
```

Now iText won't forward a row in case it doesn't fit. It will split the row in two (or more) parts, and put port of it on the current page and another part on the next page(s).